# Windows Insider Program “Something went wrong”

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-insider

I am trying to join the Windows Insider Programme in the Dev Channel.

But when clicking "Get Started", I receive this error message:

> Something went wrong. We aren't able to talk to our service at the
> moment. Please try again later.

[image: Something went wrong]

My current Windows Version is:

[image]

I have the Optional Feedback enabled.

What to I need to do to be able to join the Insider Program?

Comment: Did you 'try again later'?

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried yesterday, and today. There is no indication on the Insider Programme website, that it would have any problems.

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows Insider Preview ISO?

Comment: Go here:  https://account.microsoft.com/account  and sign in to your account. page. Make sure all is working.  Then go to your computer: Start, Settings, Update and try again there to join.

Comment: @John I did this, there is nothing wrong on my account page, or with my device, see https://imgur.com/a/qQ6s9b2. Still the same error after Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound Where exactly are the ISOs located? This link (https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso) does not work, but its the official link in the docs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/isos)

Comment: @SirChregeli - [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-insider/isos) is the proper site which contains a link to the [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to resolve this problem forever until a light bulb went off in my head! The message says exactly what the problem is, the computer cannot access the service. I have a huge HOSTS file blocking all kinds of ad and malware sites and quite possibly the service they're trying to access. As soon as I renamed my HOSTS and put back the original one, the problem went away and I was able to get W11.

Hope this helps.. Good luck!